# Does anyone know how to transfer a domain name in Plesk using an EPP code?

Tags: dns, authentication, transfer, plesk, epp

One of my friends had a forum with Freeforums.org and they bought a domain name through them. Recently he wanted to transfer the .org domain name to his own host which uses a Plesk control panel. Freeforums sent him an EPP code to transfer the domain.

How would he use the EPP code to transfer the domain?

Answer (score 2):

You friend needs to take that EPP or Authorisation code and give it to the registrar that they want to move the domain to.  The new registrar will then (normally) send an email to the registrant contacts for the domain to double check that they agree to the domain transfer.  Once the registrants agree they will start the domain transfer process.  This does not need any work to be done by your friend but this stage basically gives the losing registrar a chance to object to the transfer of the domain.  If the losing registrar does not do anything then after 5 days the registry will automatically approve the transfer and the domain will transfer to the new registrar.  If the losing registrar approves the transfer then the domain will transfer sooner. (I work for a registry and I have never seen a losing registry approve a transfer address,  they just leave them to time out)

Hope that this helps

Jonathan

Comment: In gTLDs, registrars contracts with ICANN mandate them to send specific emails to get approvals for the transfer. Also some registrars warn their customers on an outgoing transfer and also provide them an interface to explicitely deny or approve it.